# How to make rulers permanent visible?

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil

Is it possible to keep rulers displayed when leaving the Grease Pencil toolbox? I can only see the rulers when I click Grease Pencil -> Tools -> Ruler/Protactor until I press ESC.

Version: 2.79

[image]

Comment: If you look at the bottom line when ruler tool is active then you see shortcuts available and Enter to store the ruler in particular. Rulers are saved as Grease pencil layers, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24129/how-do-i-delete-a-grease-pencil-ruler

Answer (score 1):

Right now I use the good plugin MesaureIt. It is built in in Blender and can be activated in the preferences. However it lacks the possibility to measure difference shapes (boolean operator) but it is far best solution I have found till now.

[image]